# Looking for an electronic copy of Trèves and Martineau books

Tags: reference-request, schwartz-distributions, topological-vector-spaces

I would like to know if anyone has an electronic copy of the following books:

> **MR0177291** Martineau, A.; Trèves, F. Éléments de la théorie des espaces vectoriels topologiques et des distributions. Fasc. I: Éléments de la théorie des distributions. (French) Centre de Documentation Universitaire et S.E.D.E.S. Réunis, Paris 1964 ii+84 pp.

> **MR0177292** Reviewed Martineau, A.; Trèves, F. Éléments de la théorie des espaces vectoriels topologiques et des distributions. Fasc. II: Théorie élémentaire des espaces vectoriels topologiques. (French) Centre de Documentation Universitaire et S.E.D.E.S. Réunis, Paris 1962 iii+138 pp.

I tried to find them in the library of my university, however, as they are very old, I have not found them. I also tried to fid them in https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/ and https://gallica.bnf.fr/, but without success.

Comment: Google has digitized these, but they are only available with limited search because of copyright restrictions (not old enough to be out of copyright); but many university libraries have them, see https://www.worldcat.org/title/elements-de-la-theorie-des-espaces-vectoriels-topologiques-et-des-distributions/oclc/22373012 ---

Comment: Unfortunately the closest library to my university is over 2300km away, and as you said these books are not old enough to be out of copyright, and therefore, they cannot be fully digitized. I'll try to find another way to get them.